# Dependency Injection for Nest JS Interceptor is Undefined

Tags: nestjs

I have created an interceptor as shown below that I wish to use globally. I added the interceptor to my module and set it up so that nest js should handle the DI for me per [NestJS Docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors), however when I make a request to my service, I get an error indicating `Cannot read property log of undefined` so it appears that the DI is not being taken care of by NestJS.

Interceptor Code:

```js
import { Injectable, NestInterceptor, ExecutionContext, CallHandler } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { LoggingService } from './logging.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  constructor(private readonly loggingService: LoggingService) { }
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    return next
      .handle()
      .pipe(
        map((response) => {
          this.loggingService.log('Responded successfully');
          return response;
        })
      );
  }
}
```

Interceptor Module:

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { APP_INTERCEPTOR } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AuthInterceptor } from './auth.interceptor';
import { LoggingService } from './logging.service';

@Module({
  providers: [
    LoggingService,
    {
      provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
      useClass: AuthInterceptor,
    },
  ],
})
export class AuthInterceptorModule {}
```

My `app.module.ts` at the root of my application imports the AuthInterceptorModule. I am assuming I am messing something up but it is not clear to me how to fix this DI issue.

Comment: Can you add the full error you are getting, along with how you add the module to your project and **if** you add the interceptor anywhere (you shouldn't be just want to double check)

Comment: Full error is:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'log' of undefined`

I can't post full stack trace because of company policy, but log is a method of loggerService which is a dependency of AuthInterceptor per the above code. 

The interceptor is added by module to my `app.module.ts` inside of the `imports` key array. `imports: [AuthInterceptorModule]`

I am not adding the interceptor anywhere.

Comment: Nothing looks inherently wrong. Is there any more code you can share? Is the logger Singleton (default) scoped or is it request scoped? Do you have a reproduction of this? I'm not having problems with injecting a transient logger service in [nestjs-ogma](https://github.com/jmcdo29/nestjs-ogma) so I'm curious as to what's happening here

Comment: @JayMcDoniel thanks for your help! this actually ended up being an issue with a dependency I was using inside of my logger service. The logger service's dependency was request scoped and therefore that meant that my interceptor also had to be request scoped. Once I did that, this worked properly.

Comment: Glad I could help triage the issue. I've noticed if enhancers aren't working properly, it's usually a scoping issue

Answer (score 10):

I was able to resolve this one on my own after finding that my LoggingService relied on another dependency that was request scoped. Since there was a request scoped dependency in my interceptor, this meant that my interceptor also had to be request scoped.

The change to the code was simple and only required that I change the `AuthInterceptorModule` from:

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { APP_INTERCEPTOR } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AuthInterceptor } from './auth.interceptor';
import { LoggingService } from './logging.service';

@Module({
  providers: [
    LoggingService,
    {
      provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
      useClass: AuthInterceptor,
    },
  ],
})
export class AuthInterceptorModule {}
```

to

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { APP_INTERCEPTOR, Scope } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AuthInterceptor } from './auth.interceptor';
import { LoggingService } from './logging.service';

@Module({
  providers: [
    LoggingService,
    {
      provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
      scope: Scope.REQUEST,
      useClass: AuthInterceptor,
    },
  ],
})
export class AuthInterceptorModule {}
```

Comment: Thank you! I had added `@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })` to my logging class which I thought would bubble the request scope to the interceptor since I inject it, but I had to add it to the `APP_INTERCEPTOR` provider like you suggest for it to work

Comment: Thank! For anyone else who comes across this I had this same issue with the `APP_GUARD` provider.